# Syntax error in BASH script near `%` operator

Tags: bash, modulo, operation

I am writing a simple bash script to count the number of occurrences of random draws of cards. I store those in an array, and when printing out the results, for every 10 times that card is pulled, I print one single '*' in a sort of Histogram style of output.

Although, I keep receiving this error when compiling on Terminal:

---

"task1.sh: line 29: % 10 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "% 10 ")

task1.sh: line 33: % 10: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "% 10")"

---

Can't seem to figure out why though. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
#!/bin/bash
randomdraw(){
 Suits="Clubs Diamonds Hearts Spades"
 suit=($Suits)

 Denominations="2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Jack Queen King Ace"
 denomination=($Denominations)

 num_suits=${#suit[*]}
 num_denominations=${#denomination[*]}

declare -a numoccurences

declare -a suitoccurences

for ((x=0 ; $x<$loopnum ; x=$x+1));
    do
 (( numoccurences[$(( RANDOM%num_denominations ))]++ ))
 (( suitoccurences[$(( RANDOM%num_suits ))]++ ))
    done
}

echo "How Many Random Draws?: "
read loopnum
randomdraw loopnum

for ((x=0 ; $x<$num_denominations ; x=$x+1));
    do
        let "rounder=$(( ${numoccurences[x]} % 10 ))"


        if [ $rounder -ge 5 ];
            then
                let "starnum=$(( $(( ${numoccurences[x]} / 10 )) + 1 ))"
            else
                let "starnum=$(( ${numoccurences[x]} / 10 ))"
        fi
        echo "${denomination[x]}: "
        for ((k=0 ; $k<$starnum ; k=$k+1));
        do
            echo "*"
        done

    done
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `num_denominations` array is mostly empty and the

```
let "rounder=$(( ${numoccurences[x]} % 10 ))"
```

is evaluated to

```
let "rounder=$(( % 10 ))"
```

Print `numoccurences` and `suitoccurences` before asking for loop number for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to be consistent in the way you write arithmetic expressions in bash. You don't need to use `$` to introduce a variable inside an arithmetic expression. And you don't need to use `${array[idx]}` either. There's no reason to use `let` if you have arithmetic evaluation, either. So instead of

```
let "rounder=$(( ${numoccurences[x]} % 10 ))"
```

You could write:

```
(( rounder = numoccurences[x] % 10 ))
```

These don't quite do the same thing. In the first one, `${numoccurences[x]}` will be substituted with nothing if `numoccurrences` doesn't have a value corresponding to the key `$x`. In the second one, `numoccurrence[x]` will be replaced by 0, which is what you actually want. (That has nothing to do with the unnecessary `let`, since the `$((...))` arithmetic expression is evaluated before `let` is run.)

There are many other places in that script where you would be well advised to simplify your style. For example,

```
let "starnum=$(( $(( ${numoccurences[x]} / 10 )) + 1 ))"
```

would be more robust and more readable as

```
(( starnum = numoccurences[x] / 10 + 1 ))
```

Comment: nevermind... I solved the problem. Thank you guys for yhe help

Comment: @wallofkron: If you `declare -i starnum` then you don't need the `((`; you can just write `starnum=numoccurences[x]/10+1` (but you can't use spaces in that case, so the `((` style is usually more readable).

Comment: In any case all the rounder logic can be replaced by

`(( starnum = (numocurrences[x] + 5) / 10 ))`